# Using Novell.Directory.Ldap in Mono (For Android and Touch)

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, ldap, xamarin.android, novell

I want to use the Novell.Directory.Ldap library in a MonoTouch and Mono For Android project.
http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11204.html

When I compile my project in iOS simulator modus, It compiles without errors and runs correctly (in the iOS simulator).

When I compile my project in iOS device modus (to test the app with a physical device), I get this error:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider::.ctor(System.Byte[])" reference from "mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" (MT2002) (MyProject)
```

How could I solve this problem? I can't find a solution.

Should this library work for MonoTouch and Mono For Android? 
Are there better LDAP solutions for Mono?

UPDATE: I just tested it with Mono For Android. This works fine.

Comment: try with the update from the alpha channel, where they've pushed a new mono version for Xamarin.iOS

Comment: I just updated all the latest alpha updates but it doesn't fix the problem. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved.

Instead of using the dll from Novell, I downloaded all the source files of the Novell LDAP library and put them into a new library project. Then I made a reference to that library from my own Mono project.

While compiling my project and the library project, I received some errors from the library project. After solving these errors manually, it works fine for both (MonoTouch and Mono for Android).

Answer (score 7):

There's three questions in there, so I splitted my answers in three. Please read all of them :-)

> How could I solve this problem?

This is a general problem with a general solution to solve it.

The code you compiled is including a reference to `"mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0`

That's likely because you did not use the compiler provided with Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch), named `smcs`, to build the assembly. That compiler would set the references to use the right `mscorlib.dll` assembly (and report anything missing in the MOBILE profile).

The fact that it *can* work for Xamarin.Android is that it uses the JIT (just in time compilation), so missing members won't be found before **runtime** (and if execution reach that code).

OTOH Xamarin.iOS uses AOT (ahead of time compilation) since JIT'ing is not allowed (by Apple) on devices. That means missing members are found at **build** time. In this case the (managed) linker can't find the reference and issue the MT2002 error.

So the solution is to re-build the assembly using `smcs` and fix, if any, build time errors. E.g. IIRC that `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` ctor is not available (and does nothing since seeding is not possible) and should be replaced with the default ctor.

> Should this library work for MonoTouch and Mono For Android?

It should. However my *personal* experience with `Novell.Directory.Ldap` was **not** really good (code and design issues, e.g. threading, in particular with SSL enabled).

Also the code has not been updated for quite a while. You might be better served at looking at (managed or native) alternatives for your LDAP needs.

> Are there better LDAP solutions for Mono?

Sadly I have not used any other similar library so I can't suggest alternatives (but maybe other people will be able to help).